# why mysqli left join return 1 more rows?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables called : 1) products 2) product_images and it's data is like that :

```
products table :
==============
ProductID   Title      model_number
-----------------------------------
1           title1     123
2           title2     124
3           title3     125
4           title4     126
5           title5     127

product_images
==============
pi_id    p_id   product_image
------------------------------
1        1      image1
2        2      image2
3        3      image3
4        4      image4
5        1      image1
```

So If I run this query it's return 5 rows, that's correct :

```
$q=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products");
echo $n=mysqli_num_rows($q); // return 5 rows
```

But If I run this query it's return 6 rows, Why ? It's should be show 5 rows!

```
$searchQuery =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT products.ProductID,   
products.Title, products.model_number, product_images.product_image FROM 
products LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.ProductID =  
product_images.p_id ");

$isExist =  mysqli_num_rows($searchQuery); // return 6 rows
```

Can you tell me why it's return 1 more rows and How can I solved it? Thank You.

Actually I want to show all products with appropriate images.

Comment: Because you use `LEFT JOIN` and in `product_images` table you have two images for the same product(p_id = 1)

Comment: In left join if the foreign key is not there in second table also it will take. Please read about left joins here:-http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: I want to show all products with appropriate images. So if it's return 1 more row then user will not get actual number of data. So I need to show correct number of data. How can I do this ?

Comment: According to your DB structure, you can firstly download products, and then select images for this product using `select` and `IN(product_ids)` from image table or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used [LEFT JOIN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm). and you have two records with `p_id=1`; So you have 6 rows.

If you want to make `p_id` unique then use [GROUP_BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) in your query.

Write your query as below:-

```
SELECT products.ProductID,   
products.Title, products.model_number, product_images.product_image FROM 
products LEFT JOIN product_images ON products.ProductID =  
product_images.p_id GROUP BY product_images.p_id;
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But in that case you would not get all images for product

Comment: Same p_id has same image name. So there is no problem but if 1 product has multiple images then there is no need of GROUP BY clause. and if only  one image of each product needed then this query works fine :)

Comment: @sergio this query is for showing all product only. Yes a products has few images and I will show that images to other page by the product id.

Answer (score 1):

because you have 2 same `p_id=1` in `product_images`

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table

[Tutorials Point : Left join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm)